# Condition in a bucket policy to only allow specific service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

im looking for a bucket policy where I have a specific principal ID for a complete account 'arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root' which is allowed to write to a my bucket.

I now want to implement a condition which will only give firehose as a service the abillity to write to my bucket.

My current ideas were:

```
        {
            "Sid": "AllowWriteViaFirehose",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:Put*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                #*#
            }
        }
```

Whereas #*# should be the specific condition.
I already tried some things like :

**{"IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "firehose.amazonaws.com"}}**
I thought the requests would come from a firehose endpoint of AWS. But it seems not :-/

**"Condition": {"StringLike": {"aws:PrincipalArn": "*Firehose*"}}**
i thought this would work since the role which firehose uses to write files should contain a session name with something like 'firehose' in it. But it didn't work.

Any idea how to get this working?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: You identify the Kinesis Firehose service via the principal: "Service": "firehose.amazonaws.com"

Comment: Take a look at the example here - `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html#using-iam-s3`

Comment: This won’t work. The service principal is sure a good approach but only would enable the whole service without any restrictions from which account. Keep in mind that this is a two-account setup.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create a bucket policy.

Instead, assign the desired permission to an **IAM Role** and assign the role to your Kinesis Firehose.

See: [Controlling Access with Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose - Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html)

Comment: This is definitely a better way. But this won‘t work since the kinesis fh is in a different account.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for the situation where **the destination S3 bucket is in a different account**.

From [AWS Developer Forums: Kinesis Firehose cross account write to S3](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=279690), the method is:

1. Create cross account roles in Account B and enable trust relationships for Account A to assume Account B's Role.
2. Enable Bucket policy in Account B to allow Account A to write records into Account B.
3. Map Account B's S3 bucket to Firehose, had to create the firehose to point to a temporary bucket and then use AWS CLI commands to update the S3 bucket in account A.

CLI Command:

```
aws firehose update-destination --delivery-stream-name MyDeliveryStreamName --current-delivery-stream-version-id 1 --destination-id destinationId-000000000001 --extended-s3-destination-update file://MyFileName.json
```

MyFileName.json looks like the one below:

```
{
    "BucketARN": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucketname",
    "Prefix": ""
}
```